# How to test Paypal account?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want to test the paypal account. I have created merchant's account and a personal account. Now I want to test that if it is possible to transfer (virtual) money from personal account to a business (facilitator) account before going live.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple.

Login to the Paypal Sandbox and create a New Vendor and a new buyer. It will give you bogus emails and password for them, though you shouldn't need them.

Now your virtual buyer can buy as many products from your virtual vendor with imaginary money as you want.

Comment: Yes I know that but I want to test those ids. Is there any way to test them?

Answer (score 0):

This goes into your `html` page

```
<form action="https://securepayments.sandbox.paypal.com/acquiringweb" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_hosted-payment">
<input type="hidden" name="subtotal" value="50">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="HNZ3QZMCPBAAA">
<input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" value="sale">
<input type="hidden" name="return"value="https://yourwebsite.com/receipt_page.html">
<input type="submit" name="METHOD" value="Pay Now">
</form>
```

This is an example where you use the hosted model integration method. You can change the mode in the `cmd` field to suit your requirements. Refer [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/refund-payment/) for a complete list of options. `business` requires your business ID ( merchant ID). You can even try with the e-mail address of the merchant account.

More details [here](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/GB/en_GB/files/developer/HostedSolution.pdf)

Paypal documentation, although can be easily understood, is a bit difficult to implement.

Comment: This code is for creating a button and it varies from account to acount.

Comment: @PrasadPofali The code is a form post method which sends the details to the page to process payment. Did you try?

Comment: actually i hv used this type of code in one of my projects. :)